# Still getting "stream has already been operated upon or closed" error

Tags: java, java-stream, supplier

I'm reading lines from a txt file trying to get two lines at once (current and next). I use Supplier, but still get the error.

```
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName));
Supplier<Stream<String>> streamSupplier = () -> lines;
Optional<String> line = streamSupplier.get().skip(offset).findFirst();
Optional<String> nextLine = streamSupplier.get().skip(offset+1).findFirst();
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your last two lines have to have their own streams; can't reuse one after a terminal operation. All your `streamSupplier` function does is return the same value every time it's called. There's no point to it.

Comment: A regular loop is likely a better choice here, so you only have to read the file once. Or use `Files.readAllLines()` to get a List of lines if it's not a big enough file where memory becomes a concern.

Comment: `lines.skip(offset).limit(2).collect(toList())` would give you a list containing the (up to) 2 elements you seem to be interested in.

Comment: Need to compare those two values ultimately. And the file is expected to be large.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I think I'll have a closer look at limit(2) option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your supplier isn't giving you two instances of the stream: it's giving you the same one each time. `streamSupplier.get()` is no different from using `lines` directly.

If you want to read two things from the stream, skip by `offset`, then limit by 2, then collect to a list:

```
List<String> items = lines.skip(offset).limit(2).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now you can get those items from the list:

```
Optional<String> line = items.size() > 0 ? Optional.of(items.get(0)) : Optional.empty();
Optional<String> nextLine = items.size() > 1 ? Optional.of(items.get(1)) : Optional.empty();
```